# Merging little triangles into bigger ones in Kinect scan

Tags: graphics, merge, geometry, kinect

I'm not sure if this problem has solution but ill ask anyway ill be glad also for some literature for studying, and some keywords to search.

Lets say I have 3d scan made using kinect.
On the scan there is only a single wall with a door in it. Output from kinect is composed from hundreds of little triangles.
What i want to achieve is that I recognize where is the wall and where is the door and merge wall triangles into lets say few and the same thing with the door triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at mesh simplification algorithms, but before you do you should probably familiarise yourself with the fundamental concepts of 3D graphics like vertices, matrices and meshes. GDAL and PCL are two libraries that can help you with achieving what you want.

There's also a software called MeshLab, which implements many of the mentioned algorithms and could be of some help to you.